# Accessing element from reference to vector of pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, dereference

I have a reference to a vector of pointers, as follows:

```
std::vector<Object*>& objects;
```

How can I access Objects from this vector?

Comment: `*(objects[index_you_want]).doObjectFunc();` is one way.

Comment: `objects` being a reference is irrelevant, you access it the same way as a non reference vector.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I am afraid that gives me a "expression must have class type" error (I am using Visual Studio '19)

Comment: @para Got it 

Comment: @ConÓg I can't tell, since you're not really showing us what you're actually doing. Hard to tell what went wrong with something you can't even see.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I understand. My thinking is to exclude as much code as possible in questions to reduce reading, so I hope I didn't exclude anything important.
Getting a reference for the Object I want, Object *o = objects[i]; , and then proceeding to use the indirect access operator, -> , on my new pointer seems to work 

Comment: @ConÓg You excluded almost everything imprtant in your question. Are you kidding me?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I can't imagine how what further plans I have for this hypothetical object have bearing on a question relating to accessing it

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Shouldn't that have been `(*objects[index_you_want]).doObjectFunc();`?

Comment: @DanielLangr Your solution is quite helpful, thank you 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That `objects` is a reference has no direct bearing on the question -- you use a reference in exactly the same way you use a simple identifier for the same object.

Thus, you can select an individual element of the vector by any of the normal means, such as by index, by iterator, or whatever.  The result is of the vector's element type, which is `Object *`:

```
Object *o = objects[42];
```

You can access the object to which `o` points via the dereference operator (unary `*`).  Alternatively, you can use the indirect access operator (`->`) to access its methods and fields:

```
(*o).do_something();
int i = o->an_int;
```

Comment: I understand why your solution works. Thank you John 

Answer (score 1):

You can index it with `[]` as long as you don't try to access an elment outside the the vector... or to be safer, if you need to do something to every element you could use a range based for loop:

```
for(auto& object : objects) 
   object->someFunction();
```

Comment: Since `object` is an `Object*`, it'd need to be `object->someFunction();`.

Comment: Yep, that works once I use "->" 

Comment: @Eljay Well noticed, I've edited